# Store arrays in unique variables at each for loop iteration in python

Tags: python, arrays

Currently i am working on a python project using windows platform in which i need to deal with images.
Under this, i need to divide my image into several segments and then store them as unique images.
For this, i need to convert my image into floating point array which would then be segmented
The segmentation part is sorted.
But the point where i am stuck is storing of these newly generated arrays.

For example if my loop runs for 6 times, 6 new arrays would be generated (of large size say 300 X 420) and i need to store them in unique variables for each iteration such that they do not overlap each other.

How do i do that?

How can i store newly generated arrays of my loop into different arrays for each iteration? I need these arrays afterwards so it is important for me to store them.

The number of arrays generated would be dynamic too!

this is the code:

`

```
#read image and do its segmentation
 image = cv2.imread("Path to input image\\___.png")
 segments = slic(img_as_float(image), compactness=100.0, n_segments = 2,sigma = 5) 
 #loop to generate individual segments and to store them individually
 for (i, segVal) in enumerate(np.unique(segments)):
    print "[x] inspecting segment %d" % (i)
    mask = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype = "uint8")
    mask[segments == segVal] = 255
    s2 = np.array(segments);
    bb= (cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask = mask) )
    #above the unique array is generated
    #store the generated array as unique image at desired location
    cv2.imwrite('Path to store\\__.png', bb)
```

`

NOTE: the arrays generated are already 2-D and of the size 327 X 500.
So please give me a solution to store 2-D arrays.
It does now matter what we use dictionary, list or new variables :)

**EDIT**

As per some solutions, i tried to insert the newly generated arrays into another big array. But still there are some errors which i am getting. The new code chunk is:

```
#read image and do its segmentation
 image = cv2.imread("Path to input image\\___.png")
 segments = slic(img_as_float(image), compactness=100.0, n_segments = 2,sigma = 5) 
 #loop to generate individual segments and to store them individually
 for (i, segVal) in enumerate(np.unique(segments)):
    print "[x] inspecting segment %d" % (i)
    mask = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype = "uint8")
    mask[segments == segVal] = 255
    s2 = np.array(segments);
    results= []
    bb= (cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask = mask) )
    results.append(bb)
    #above the unique array is generated and appended into a big array
    #store the generated array as unique image at desired location
    cv2.imwrite('Path to store\\__.png', results(i))
```

The errors which i am getting are:

list object is not callable for this line `cv2.imwrite('Path to store\\__.png', results(i))`

What changes shall be done?

Comment: You could store everything inside one big array

Comment: You can go with a 2-d array or a dictionary. Can you share the sample code used?

Comment: They arrays are already 2-D and huge. Please share an example code to explain how to store them inside one big array. @moritzg

Comment: 327x500 is a fairly small size for an array. And what you want is to use a list, dynamicly generated variables are a bad idea in general. Just create an empty list `l`  before the loop and append each new array to it as you go, to access the arrays after you just have to call `l[2]` or any other number.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store them in unique variables. You can, however, create a 2-dimensional array to store all of them. For example, if there are 3 generated arrays: `[1,2,3]`, `[4,5,6]`, and `[7,8,9]`, the structure of the 2-dimensional array will be as follows:

```
[[1, 2, 3],
[4, 5, 6],
[7, 8, 9]]
```

Then, to access the individual arrays, you can simply access the desired index, followed by the index of the element you want. For example, to get the second element of the first array, you can say something like `arr[0][1]`. This will return `2`.

**EDIT**

It doesn't matter if the individual arrays are already 2-D. Just add another dimension. For example,

```
# make a big array
bigarray = []

#read image and do its segmentation
 image = cv2.imread("Path to input image\\___.png")
 segments = slic(img_as_float(image), compactness=100.0, n_segments = 2,sigma = 5) 
 #loop to generate individual segments and to store them individually
 for (i, segVal) in enumerate(np.unique(segments)):
    print "[x] inspecting segment %d" % (i)
    mask = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype = "uint8")
    mask[segments == segVal] = 255
    s2 = np.array(segments);
    bb= (cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask = mask) )
    #above the unique array is generated
    #store the generated array as unique image at desired location
    cv2.imwrite('Path to store\\__.png', bb)

    # push the generated 2d array to the big array
    bigarray.append(bb)
```

Then, let's say you want to access the first 2-D array, you can say `bigarray[0]`. If you want to access the upper left pixel of the first 2-D array, you can say `bigarray[0][0][0]`.

Comment: my arrays are 2-dimensional. Any method to store the 2-D arrays into another array?

Comment: Just add another dimension. Arrays can be 3-dimensional :) So it will be something like arr[0][0][1].

Comment: one example please. like how can it be helpful to my code? @ThomasJamesTiam-Lee

Comment: thanks for your solution @thomasjamestiam-lee ! :) But there are various errors which i am encountering while using this big_array solution. I will edit my question and would show the errors which i am getting in it. Please check and help! Thankyou